# The set of all sets of the universe?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can't understand Russell's paradox. What I understand is that Russell's paradox arises because the set of all sets that are members of themselves is empty. That it's impossible to find a set that's a member of itself, but one can define the set of all sets of the universe that clearly contain itself. Does it mean that there is no set of all sets of the universe?

Please, make answers as simple as possible, I'm nearly ignorant in set theory.

Comment: I think you are confusing something. Russell's paradox doesn't exhibit the non-existence of sets which are members of themselves. It rather says that there is no set containing all sets which aren't members of themselves.

Answer (score 10):

[Russell's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox), as well other paradoxes ([Cantor's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_paradox), [Burali-Forti paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox)) simply tell us that some collections that we can define are not sets. There are two ways to overcome these things:

1. In modern set theory such as [ZFC (Zermelo-Fraenkel with Choice)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) the *collection* of all sets is not a set. This is why there is a notion of *class*, it simply means a collection which we can define. In the case of "all the sets" we just define it to be $\{x\mid x=x\}$.
2. There are, however, set theories in which the collection of all sets is a set. One example is [NF (New Foundations)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations). In this theory we limit the formulas which define new sets, and so Russell's collection cannot become a set. This means that we cannot prove from NF that the collection defined by Russell's paradox is a set itself, so no contradiction arises.

---

**Further reading material:**

- [difference between class, set , family and collection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172966/difference-between-class-set-family-and-collection/173002#173002)
- [Is $V$ under ZFC really a proper class?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34614/is-v-under-zfc-really-a-proper-class/34617#34617)
- [Difference between a class and a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139330/difference-between-a-class-and-a-set/139337#139337)

Comment: My understanding of NF is that it can express the collection of "sets that are not members of themselves" just as well as ZFC can (that is, the collection is not a set, but you can choose to abbreviate $x\not\in x$ as $x\in\mathbf B$ as long as you don't pretend $\mathbf B$ is something that can be the value of a variable). In ZFC what prevents it from being a set is that ZF comprehension requires a preexisting superset; in NF it is because the formula $x\not\in x$ is syntactically disallowed in the set comprehension axiom. But you can use the formula as much as you like _outside_ that axiom.

Comment: @Henning: Yes. That is a more accurate depiction of the affairs. I was trying to be less accurate and technical, and give a readable explanation though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, is NF a single theory ("In this theory...") or a set of theories? NFU, TSTU, NF_n, .... ?

Comment: @alancalvitti: NF is a theory, like ZF. It has variants, much like ZF.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, and much like ZF, ZFC, ZFU, ZF+AD, ZF+AFA &c, the different variants can lead to distinct results. What is the use of calling something a theory if variations therein can lead, sometimes, to starkly opposed results (eg the disasters in Herrlich's *Axiom of Choice*).

Comment: @alancalvitti: I really don't understand what you are trying to say. Are you suggesting that the fact that changing one axiom to another leads to different consequences makes the word "theory" an unfit name? How does this have anything to do with my answer, or wih mathematics for that matter?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I'm just trying to understand by contrasting with physics, where for example, special and general relativity are considered distinct theories since they have different assumptions and different conclusions. I agree that the term "theory" is a scientific one, not really part of maths.

Comment: @alancalvitti: That is something for a whole other question, which might be borderline for this site since it seems to be a linguistic concern rather than a mathematical one. Note that physical theories do not consistute of logical postulates, and that mathematical theories cannot be refuted by experiments. This is similar to asking why is "right" can mean a direction when it can also imply confirmation of something being said.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, do you know that Hilbert said there is no difference between the methods of physics and the methods of geometry? That may be a stretch since physics always involves motion (time) whereas geometry might not (perhaps through group action). Physics does use logical postulates, eg Modus Ponens. Without it, reasoning could not proceed. The key difference I think is whereas maths doesn't care about the assumption but only about the inferences from the assumptions, in physics not only the inferences but also the assumptions must be matched to the system under study.

Comment: @alancalvitti: let me take a swing in namedropping. Do you know that Hiobert said that there is no unsolvable problem in mathematics? Interestingly enough there are many of them in mathematics. Let me give you a great example: Let $G$ be a group. Is $G$ abelian?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, one mode of solving problems is to introduce new axioms, that's fine. I meant to say above is that logical postulates are part of reasoning including physical reasoning. I would agree that a small subset of math can be decided  experimentally, eg four-color map theorem, but not much of maths that deal with infinite structures can be so decided.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that (in ZFC) a set cannot be a *member* of itself has no real connection to the Russell Paradox. It is a consequence of the Axiom of Regularity..

The Axiom of Regularity was introduced by von Neumann for purely technical reasons that had nothing to do with paradox avoidance. For one thing, it makes the development of the theory of ordinals smoother. However, set theory can be perfectly well developed without Regularity.

The axioms of ZFC are intended to be (i) powerful enough to allow all the set constructions that we need for a mathematics based on Set Theory and (ii) not so powerful as to lead to a contradiction.

One cannot *know for sure* that inconsistency has been avoided. But the cheap kind of inconsistency that doomed the logic of Frege is, one hopes, made impossible by putting limitations on how one is allowed to construct sets. (Very) roughly speaking, one is allowed to construct a set from the contents of an already constructed set (here the major exception is the Axiom of Infinity, along with parts of the Axiom scheme of Replacement).

Comment: Also, if ZFC without Regularity is consistent, then it is does not introduce any new inconsistency to explicitly postulate (instead of Regularity) that there exists a set that is a member of itself.

Comment: To fill in a detail on Henning's note, one axiom that broadens the statement 'there is a set that is a member of itself' is known as the _Anti-Foundation Axiom_ (AFA), introduced by Peter Aczel; it basically states that 'any membership graph you can produce (with a designated node representing your set, and all other nodes reachable from it) corresponds to a unique well-defined set'.

Answer (score 5):

In case you want a short answer that does not attempt to add too much perspective:

1. Russell's paradox does not prove or require that $\{x\mid x\in x\}$ is empty. It proves that $\{x\mid x\not\in x \}$ *cannot exist as a set* (which is different from being empty -- an empty set does exist), no matter whether there are sets that contain themselves or not.
2. In ordinary ZFC set theory there is indeed no "set of all sets of the universe". (But see Asaf's answer) .
3. In ordinary ZFC set theory $\{x\mid x\in x\}$ is indeed the empty set -- and *therefore* $\{x\mid x\in x\}$ happens to exist there. (But see André's answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have had a problem understanding this before. Here's what I can provide.

The Russell's paradox says that it is impossible to define the set $U$ of all things if $U$ is also considered one of "all things". By impossible, I mean if you allow $U$ to exist, you will violate one of many intuitive rules. You may, as a result, convince yourself that maybe some "intuitive" rules are not supposed to hold as a way to resolve Russell's paradox.

*A property $x \notin x$ is considerably nice, so intuitively it should not pose a problem if I pick a subset $V \subseteq U$ by picking elements that satisfy $x \notin x$. However, Russell's paradox says that if you define $V$ like this, you will not know whether $V \in V$ or $V \notin V$. This is considered a contradiction to our basic assumption that you must be able to tell whether $x \in y$ or $x \notin y$ if $y$ is a set.*

There are several ways to resolve Russell's paradox. I will list some here.

1. Some may think that the statement like $x \in x$ is actually not so nice. In fact, a set can only contain itself if it's infinitely nested (informally speaking), so it's not hard for me to convince myself that I won't find much use of that in real life. We can choose to disallow sets that contain themselves from being defined, *i.e.*, refuse the existence of such sets. This restriction will render the question "Is $x \in x$?" an invalid statement. This resolves Russell's paradox by making the definition of $V$ invalid. But however practically-looking this is, we know consciously that we lose the ability to define some sets that we were able to define.
2. If you drop the assumption that either $x \in y$ or $x \notin y$ must be true, then the existence of $V$ doesn't seem so problematic. This may be one of reasons people invented intuitionistic logic.
3. You can expand the universe by adding more things that are not considered "sets", then you define $U$ as a "collection" of all sets, and $V = \{x \in U\ |\ x \notin x\}$. This way, $U$ does not contain "everything", but it does contain every set. $U$ itself cannot be a set, or the definition of $V$ will cause a paradox. This solution is used quite a lot. Objects in this system are called "classes". A class that belongs to other classes is called a set. A class that is not a set is called a "proper class". Note that you still cannot have the class of all classes, or the Russell's paradox will appear again, with the word "class" replacing "set".

Anyway, the root of all evil is self-referencing. I feel that it's a common theme in all branches of mathematics.